# VBA - Put a textbox at the end of a variable table

Tags: vba, excel

For my project, I need to do a layout of a pricelist.
We add products everyday so, I wrote a macro to do a variable table.

```
Sheets("A").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(Range("B1"), Range("B1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)), , xlYes).Name = _
    "Tableau1"
Range("Tableau1[#All]").Select
Sheets("A").ListObjects("Tableau1").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9"
```

The problem here : I want to put a textbox at the end of the table (For the conditions when you buy something you know...), but I don't know how to put it... I already tried `Range("E").End(xlDown).Row` to teh top condition of the textbox to put it at the end, but my textbox is placed in the middle of the table, I don't know why...

Here's my actual code for the design of the textbox :

```
Sheets("A").Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 60, _
      Range("E").End(xlDown).Row, Range("B:L").Width, 60).Select
```

Do you have any solution for my problem ?

Thank's in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: `Range.Row` is the row number. `Range.Top` is the position of the top of the range. `Range.Offset(1).Top` is the position of the bottom of the range if the range is 1 row in height. But what is the "E" in your `Range("E")`?

Comment: E is a column where all the cells are full.

Comment: Hm, but `Range("E")` will not be the column `E`. `Range("E:E")` would be. And in `Range("E1").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Top` not a whole column is needed but the first cell from which the `End` shall be processed. Maybe it is not `E1` for you, then you must adapt.

Comment: Thanks ! 'Range("E1").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Top' is working ! @AxelRichter

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
Sheets("A").Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 60, _
      Range("E1").End(xlDown).Row, Range("B:L").Width, 60).Select
```